# Run Anaconda-Scrapy as Cron job

Tags: python, cron, scrapy, anaconda, centos7

I am trying to run a scrapy (installed with anaconda2) crawler as a cron job. No luck so far.

Here is cron command:

```
* * * * * sh /home/username/anaconda2/folder/getdata.sh
```

The cron runs every 1 min ( I checked the log file, it seem to be ok)
And here is the code inside the sh file:

```
#!/home/username/anaconda2/bin/python
cd /home/username/anaconda2/crawler_folder
PATH=$PATH:/home/username/anaconda2/bin
export PATH
scrapy crawl spider
```

The sh code executes as expected in the terminal but not as a cron job.
Can you please help

Comment: You may want to double check your cron logs then, for example following https://askubuntu.com/a/121560. Maybe `scrapy` command is not available when cron runs it (you could check with `which scrapy` within that `.sh` script)

Comment: If I did so, where can I see the result? In the log it only shows that the cron job was performed.

Comment: Have you read that askubuntu answer? If you do `* * * * * sh /home/username/anaconda2/folder/getdata.sh >> /home/username/myscript.log 2>&1`, do you see a scrapy crawl being launched?

Comment: /home/username/myscript.log 2>&1?? I don't see such a file? Should I run it manually in the terminal?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This worked for me as the .sh file and the cron job was unchanged.

```
#!/home/username/anaconda2/bin/bash
PATH=/home/username/anaconda2/bin:home/username/anaconda2/sbin
cd /home/username/anaconda2/crawler_folder && scrapy crawl spider
```